# A game using two canvas making jump effect slower and slower.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple game which includes two canvas. They are identical and placed one on top of another. The first canvas1 is for auto scrolling a background image. And the second Canvas2 is for an object which will jump to a certain height upon pressing the forward arrow key. The canvas2 which is used for making the object jump is placed on top of the canvas1 which is used to auto scroll image. The code which is used to make the jump works fine when used seperately on a single canvas. But in this game it is slower and as time passes it becomes slower and slower. What is the problem and how it can be fixed?

FIDDLES:

[GAME FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/humptydumpty45/A3aYw/3/)

[background image which scrolls](http://postimg.org/image/53i8j8htt/80f1683d/)

[object which jumps](http://postimg.org/image/qvhbdq2rd/e8bbf727/)

[jump code works normal when used seperately](http://jsfiddle.net/humptydumpty45/dNyJV/)

CSS:

```
<head>
<style>

*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
body{position:relative;}
#mydiv{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:black;
}
#mycanvas1{

margin-top:50px;
margin-left:250px;
border:1px solid white;

}
#mycanvas2{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:250px;
border:1px solid white;


}

</style>
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<canvas id="mycanvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="mycanvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:
(FOR SCROLLING)

```
var canvas1=document.getElementById("mycanvas1");
canvas1.width=500;
canvas1.height=500;
var ctxbg=canvas1.getContext('2d');
var canvas2=document.getElementById("mycanvas2");
canvas2.width=500;
canvas2.height=500;
ctxbox=canvas2.getContext('2d');

var velocity=50;
var bgImage=new Image();
bgImage.addEventListener('load',drawImage,false);
bgImage.src="images/bg.png";
function drawImage(time){

        var framegap=time-lastRepaintTime;
        lastRepaintTime=time;
        var translateX=velocity*(framegap/1000);
        ctxbg.clearRect(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
        var pattern=ctxbg.createPattern(bgImage,"repeat-x");
        ctxbg.fillStyle=pattern;
        ctxbg.rect(-translateX,0,bgImage.width,bgImage.height);
       ctxbg.fill();
          ctxbg.translate(translateX,0);

    requestAnimationFrame(drawImage);


}
var lastRepaintTime=window.performance.now();
requestAnimationFrame(drawImage);
```

(FOR JUMPING)

```
var gravity=0.1;
var keypressed=false;
var boxImage=new Image();

boxImage.src="images/grass.jpg";
function box(x,y){
   this.x=x;
   this.y=y;
   this.speed=0;
   this.image=boxImage;
   }
   box.prototype.hop=function(){
          if(this.y+this.image.height>canvas2.height){
              this.y=500-36;
              this.speed=0;
              }else{

          this.speed=this.speed+gravity;
          this.y+=this.speed;
          }
   }
  box.prototype.draw=function (){

   ctxbox.drawImage(this.image,this.x,this.y);

}  
 var greenBox=new box(10,450);  
requestAnimationFrame(function loop(){

  ctxbox.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
  greenBox.draw();
  if(keypressed==true){
  greenBox.speed=-5
   keypressed=false;

  }
greenBox.hop();

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
});

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){

       if(e.keyCode==38){

      keypressed=true;



       }



},false);
```

Comment: It's not getting slow on my computer. Maybe you are interested in using a lightweight game framework like [melonJS](http://melonjs.org/)?

Comment: are you talking about scrolling?here jumping gets slow not the scrolling (in case you are talking about scrolling background)         how can i use melonJS .it is my first game.never used any thing like this before

Comment: The jumping isn't getting slow on my computer, too. melonJS, look at their page end examples, it's very easy to use.

Comment: Have you tried using any developer tools in your browser to take a profile and see if there is a memory leak or other performance issue. I'm going to say it's your browser potentially, because I too have tested and found no performance loss. At least within a 10 minute test using firefox (latest), which seems reasonable enough to determine any issues.

Comment: have you checked the fourth fiddle .the same code there works differently .if you check it you will have an idea.i don't know if there is any problem on my browser.they are acting differently